# Unable to connect to redis container from python - ECS cluster services connected using Service connect

Tags: redis, amazon-ecs, redis-py, ecs-service-connect

I have a very simple application with python and redis where python code sends numbers to the redis server using redis-py package. The application works perfectly while deployed on my local machine via docker compose.

The issue arises when I deploy the same application to AWS ECS cluster as an ECS service. AWS connects between ECS services using a method called "service connect".

For showing the error message easily, I will paste the screenshot of connecting via redis-cli from inside the python docker container instead of python tracebacks.

The error message is as follows:

---

### [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5lKU.png)

I have checked the following:

1. Ensured that port 6379 is open from python container
2. Hostname "celeryredis" is running a redis server and the python container is able to access it.

---

### [telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wU4Z.png)

### [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI7dh.png)

3. Redis-server is not authenticated. But I have tried setting a password to the redis server and while connecting to it from the python code still raises the issue.
4. I have also tried by explicitly setting the protocol via:
   r = redis.from_url("redis://celeryredis:6379/0")
5. I have tried using awsvpc network mode in AWS and the issue persists.
6. I have ensured that we are using tcp protocol.
7. I have tried to use --loglevel as debug. But it does not show any connected clients.
8. When connected from a python terminal, I am getting a 400 Bad request.

---

### [redis-py-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUKkd.png)

I expect to get "OK" when I run ping() from the redis-cli

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I think serviceconnect in ECS only supports HTTP/HTTPS traffic? I see conflicting documentation though

Comment: I am having similar issue, redis image runs successfully buy when running my worker in another task it does not seem to connect to redis